# How can I make an installer window resizable, using WiX?

Tags: wix

I'm building an installer using WiX, with a custom UI based on the Minimal interface. When running the installer, I've noticed that its window has no resize grip in the lower right hand corner and its maximize button is disabled. How can I enable those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt this is at all possible with the Windows Installer UI.

The WiX element [`<Dialog/>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_dialog.htm) relies on the [Dialog table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368286.aspx), that is, it can only do what the table lets it to. The table doesn't define a setting for re-size button and/or grip, neither via direct columns, nor via [dialog style bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368285.aspx).

Comment: The WiX dialog properties can be found [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_dialog.htm). They don't include any properties for maximize or grip.